# Why do setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) and findViewById(R.id.example) not use dot notation to reference an object?

Tags: java, android

My understanding is that the only time dot notation is not used with a method is when you are operating within the same class as that method. However, both of these methods are used in the mainActivity class of android apps without any reference. According to their documentation they are instance methods so I really can't see why they compile without using dot notation. Here's the specific code I'm referring to:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //No dot notation for an instance method of Activity

    //Create Buttons
    Button addBtn = findViewById(R.id.buttonAddition); //Same here
```

Comment: Because they are present in the parent class.

Answer (score 1):

This is related not to android or Java, but to object oriented programming.
In this case, you don't need an explicit references because that methods are implemented in the super class of yours (i'm asumming that code is inside an activity)

If you check the documentation of Activity (or any of it's subclasses like AppCompatActivity, FragmentActivity) they define:

```
@Override
public void setContentView(@LayoutRes int layoutResID) {
    getDelegate().setContentView(layoutResID);
}
```

In object oriented programming, a subclass (yours in this case) inherits all the methods and fields of its parent/s, as it they were their own.

If you'd like to be more explicit, you can use:

```
super.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

There, you have your explicit  dot notataion with the reference to the parent, but it is redundant in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Your MainActivity class should be defined like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    (...)
}
```

(or extends [`AppCompatActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatActivity) if you use AndroidX)

This tells your class inherits the [`Activity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity) class. That means all of the  `Activity` class's predefined methods are inherited by your class (and some of them can be overridden). You just see overridden methods or additional methods in your MainActivity. There are other inherited methods although they are invisible or omitted.